# Iterate through arraylist and show alert dialog for each item in array list and then move to next item when click positive button

Tags: android, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I am creating an auto caller app in which i have used a button which takes data from arrayList, iterate through the arraylist and ask user on each element if want to do next call or pause on that for this i have used alert dialog, but the loop is not getting pause on each element it went to the last element and show alert dialog for that contact number.

```
  private List<ContactEntity> mContactsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ContactEntity c;
    private int i = 0;

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.start_call) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Call Started" + mContactsList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startAutoCall();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

 private void startAutoCall() {
        if (mContactsList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Import Contacts ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            c = mContactsList.get(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + c.getPersonContactNumber()));
            startActivity(intent);

            while(i < mContactsList.size()){
                c = mContactsList.get(i);

                Log.d(TAG, "startAutoCall: " + c.getId());
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Auto Dialer Start");


                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + c.getPersonContactNumber()));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                i++;

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to build alert dialog inside a loop. Instead, create one and update the value for each element in the list on button click. Override onClickListener for the dialog so that you can control the flow better.

Here's a snippet in kotlin.

```
if(mContactList.isNotEmpty()){
    c = mContactList.get(i)
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Auto Dialer Start")
    builder.setMessage("Your message here...")
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null)

    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.setOnShowListener{ dialogInterface->
        val btnOk = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        btnOk.setOnClickListener{
            //Your code here...

            if(i == mContactList.size-1){
                dialogInterface.dismiss()
            }else {
               i++
               c = mContactList.get(i)
            }
        }
    }
    dialog.show()
}
```